# Use differential to approximate $\sqrt{16+8h^4} = 4+h^4$ for small h?

Tags: derivatives

Ok here is the work I have done so far:

Let $f(x)=x^{1/2}$

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}$

I know I'm supposed to choose one other $x$ value close to $16+8h^4$ and find the change in $x$ and change in $y$, but I don't know what other $x$ value to choose!

I don't know what Taylor or linear approximation is. I am just going by what my professor is teaching us. He didn't even mention these. I also don't know why this question is on hold; I didn't leave anything out that I don't think I have.

Comment: Are you suppose to know Taylor or at leat linear approximation ?

Comment: @JohnBentin. It is OK.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: You are right. Sorry. (+1 for your answer)

Comment: why is this on hold?

Comment: NVM I FIGURED OUT THE ANSWER! How do I post what I did on this post?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $$f(x)=\sqrt{16+8x^4}$$ and its successive derivatives $$f'(x)=\frac{16 x^3}{\sqrt{8 x^4+16}}$$ $$f''(x)=\frac{4 \sqrt{2} x^2 \left(x^4+6\right)}{\left(x^4+2\right)^{3/2}}$$ $$f'''(x)=-\frac{48 \sqrt{2} x \left(x^4-2\right)}{\left(x^4+2\right)^{5/2}}$$ $$f''''(x)=\frac{48 \sqrt{2} \left(5 x^8-28 x^4+4\right)}{\left(x^4+2\right)^{7/2}}$$ All the first derivatives are zero if $x=0$; only the fourth appears with a constant term in numerator and this term makes $f''''(0)=24$.

Now, apply Taylor and taking into account the fact that, for $x=0$, $f'=f''=f'''=0$, you then have $$f(x)\approx f(0)+\frac{x^4}{4!}f''''(0)$$ and, since $4!=24$, then the result.

I am almost $100$% sure that there is something simpler to do but I don't get it for the time being. What I propose is correct but very tedious.

Comment: @Integrator. Sorry, I didn't ! What I should have done. Cheers :-)